# Output 2 integer numbers separated by comma to array in C

Tags: c, file-io, delimiter

I'm newbie C-er

What I want is to output the numbers from text file separated by comma, for example.

Input file:

```
1,2/3,4/5,6/7,8
```

Expected output is:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
```

So it means 2 numbers separated by comma will be taken as a pair.

Below is my code which just gives 2 first number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("somenumbers.txt", "r");

int numberArray[6];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    fscanf(myFile, "%d,", &numberArray[i] );

}

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
       printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[i]);
    }

fclose(myFile);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite code like here (only conceptual piece of code).

```
int numberArray[6];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i+=2)
{
    fscanf(myFile, "%d,%d/", &numberArray[i],&numberArray[i+1]);

}

for (i = 0; i < 6; i+=2)
{
       printf("Number is: %d,%d\n\n", numberArray[i], numberArray[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. I did like you before but forget to put "i+=2 " and it gave error core dumped . Thanks!